# Error occurred while converting .proto files into .py, using protobuf v3.8.0 (windows)

Tags: python

I just stepped into deep learning, and am trying to implement a real-time object detection model. But I'm stuck at "trying to convert .proto files into .py". I am using protobuf v3.8.0 (windows) for the purpose. The command used in anaconda prompt is:

```
protoc object_detection/protos/*.proto --python_out=.
```

The above code preceded with the path to protoc bin becomes

```
Tensorflow\protoc\bin\protoc object_detection/protos/*.proto --python_out=.
```

And this throws an error saying "no such file/directory".
Altering the environment variables was no help either.
How do I fix this?

Comment: What are you saying? That the first command works and the second one gives an error? Or do they both give the same error?  And what is the error message, ***exactly**?*

Answer (score 0):

Use  PROTOBUF 3.4 & copy protoc file into `C:\Tensorflow\models\research` directory. It worked for me in that way .